# Export inventory data from and import order data into demandware

Tags: e-commerce, demandware

How can I export inventory information (e.g. on availability for a specific product) from demandware to another ecommerce vendor? Is there something like a demandware API which I can call to get this information? Similarly, is it possible for demandware to receive orders from another ecommerce vendor?

The background is that for a system based on demandware, I would like to integrate it with other ecommerce platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do all these sort or Import/Export using Jobs.

Have a look at the following links for a better understanding:

- Integration framework: https://xchange.demandware.com/docs/DOC-11159
- Jobs: https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OrderManagement/Concepts/Jobs.html?resultof=%22%4a%6f%62%73%22%20%22%6a%6f%62%22%20

Comment: The Integration Framework is deprecated. The components it defines can be migrated to the new Jobs Framework. The Jobs Framework should be used instead of the Integration Framework for the scheduling of tasks. Additionally, you can indeed access inventory and place orders via the Open Commerce APIs. See: https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/18.6/usage/ShopAPIResources.html?cp=0_12_3

Answer (score 1):

Please check ExportInventoryLists pipelet https://documentation.demandware.com/DOC2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fpipeletapi%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fpipelet.ExportInventoryLists.html&resultof=%22ExportInventoryLists%22%20%22exportinventorylist%22%20.

Also, you can try with Integration-Framework

Comment: Since I don't have access to the documentation right now, would you please clarify - if I have a list of orders from another seller (of my product) in the form of a spreadsheet or json data, I can simply import it? How about exporting - can I send inventory stock information to a third party seller in excel or json format? Cheers